# Why can't I catch KeyboardInterrupt during raw_input?

Tags: python, interrupt

here is a test case.

```
try:
    targ = raw_input("Please enter target: ")
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "Cancelled"
print targ
```

My output is as follows when I press ctrl+c-

```
NameError: name 'targ' is not defined
```

My intention is for the output to be "Cancelled". Any thoughts to as why this happens when I attempt to catch a KeyboardInterrupt during raw_input?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In above code, when exception raised, targ is not defined. You should print only when exception is not raised.

```
try:
    targ = raw_input("Please enter target: ")
    print targ
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "Cancelled"
```

Answer (score 2):

The error occurs because if a `KeyboardInterrupt` is raised, the variable `targ` never gets initialised.

```
try:
    targ = raw_input("Please enter target: ")
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "Cancelled"

Please enter target: 
Cancelled

>>> targ

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#19>", line 1, in <module>
    targ
NameError: name 'targ' is not defined
```

When, it does not occur,

```
try:
    targ = raw_input("Please enter target: ")
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "Cancelled"


Please enter target: abc

>>> targ
'abc'
```

You could change your code to print `targ` if an exception is not raised, by printing it in the `try` statement, see the following demo.

```
try:
    targ = raw_input("Please enter target: ")
    print targ
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "Cancelled"


Please enter target: abc
abc

try:
    targ = raw_input("Please enter target: ")
    print targ
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "Cancelled"


Please enter target: 
Cancelled
```