# output of input dialog box when Cancel button is pressed - Python

Tags: python, input, dialog

This is in `Python`. I am requesting input through the generic `getInput('1 or 2?')` and I set up a `while loop` so that it will continue requesting input until the user puts 1 or 2. I want to `stop` the loop if the user clicks the `Cancel` button, but don't know what `output` that returns in order to add it into my if statement. How do I reference the user input of selecting the Cancel button?

```
input = False
while input == False:
    answer = getInput('1 or 2')
    if answer == '1':
        do this
        input = True
    elif answer == '2':
        do this
        input = True
    elif answer == False:  #Don't know what to put here to reference the input of
        input = True       #clicking the Cancel button to exit the input...
    else:
        getWarningReply('Invalid answer. Please enter 1 or 2.', 'OK')
        pass
```

getInput is not a user defined function. All I do is type getInput('Whatever') and it opens a dialog box with 'Ok' or 'Cancel' buttons and a space for user input. Same thing as input()

Comment: use `continue` in your loop until the user enters what you want, what is your cancel button?

Comment: `getInput` is not a builtin function in python as far as I am aware ...

Comment: Without seeing your `getInput()` function, it's hard to diagnose, but possible answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18149870/why-cant-i-catch-keyboardinterrupt-during-raw-input)

Answer (score 0):

printing stuff can be helpful alot of the time

```
input = False
while input == False:
    answer = getInput('1 or 2')
    print "GOT : %s"%answer
```

now just hit cancel and see what it says .... I dont know what `getInput` is but I assume cancel will return 0, false or none

it is likely sufficient to say

```
elif not answer:
     print "User clicked cancel"
```

but really just print it as shown above and you should know exactly what clicking cancel results in

(apparently you checked and its `None`) so

```
elif answer is None: 
    input=True
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Joran Beasley, I hadn't thought of that. Turns out, when you press the Cancel button, it simply returns `None`
The if statement it was looking for is

```
elif answer == None:
    input = True
```

Comment: you should not have this as an answer .... feel free to edit your original question with the info however ... also you should probably use `elif answer is None` with none its a good idea to use the `is` comparator